# Turned off computer while using recovery partition

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, boot, partition-recovery

I was using the recovery partition on my ASUS computer to reinstall Windows XP and everything was going smoothly until the setup jammed. I waited for like 30 minutes and nothing happened so I pressed the power button to switch the computer off. I have Qimo 2.0 installed (for fun) which is based on Ubuntu 10.04 and when I turned the computer on, it went to grub rescue and displayed 'Unknown filesystem'. When I booted into the Qimo live CD to use GParted, it couldn't detect any partitions and at the bottom of the window it said 'Scanning dev/sda1' all the way until 'Scanning dev/sda100'. I don't even have that many partitions! The number kept increasing until the computer lagged. After that, I tried using the recovery CD but all I saw was a blank screen. I think the problem lies with the hard drive. Maybe it's corrupted or something.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind... Found out the answer my own self. First, I wiped the entire hard drive by filling it with zeros in the terminal using the Qimo live CD. Then, I used GParted to create a partition table  and a partition. Lastly, I used the recovery CD and lived happily ever after...